# How to make EditText Can Handles 14 KB text (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-edittext, large-text

**In summary, I have an app that allows you to upload books for other users so they can read your books, The problem is when I'm adding a large chapter it stops in the middle of the text and doesn't accept more.**

[image: 14 KB text]

[image: EditText]

**As you can see in this image it doesn't handle the rest of the text.**

here is XML for the EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etChapterBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvChapterBody"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
        android:autofillHints="no"
        android:background="@drawable/style_stroke"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/body"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:paddingHorizontal="7dp"
        android:paddingVertical="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/purple_4"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

**So is it a limits problem or something else?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing inside a ScrollView.The EditText is constrained by the available space .
Increasing the space available should solve the issue.

Comment: isn't `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` do this

Comment: yes it does but it is still constrained by the space available .. Since it's a very big string..